# Undefined index when trying to get result from JSON to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I received error when trying to call single array from `json_decode()`

> Undefined Index AccontNumber

And I have try to use Isset to the variable and doesnt get any result, Where do I doing wrong ?

```
    $this->getToken();
    $path = '/banking/v2/corporates/BCAAPI2016/accounts/0201245680/statements?StartDate=2016-09-01&EndDate=2016-09-01';
    $method = 'GET';
    $data = array();
    $this->getSignature($path, $method, $data);
    $headers = array(
      'X-BCA-Key: '.self::$api_key,
      'X-BCA-Timestamp: '.self::$timestamp,
      'Authorization: Bearer '.self::$access_token,
      'X-BCA-Signature: '.self::$signature,
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Origin: '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
      );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::$main_url.$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        ));
    $output = curl_exec($ch); // This is API Response
    curl_close($ch);
//this part I get error
    $result = json_decode($output,true);

    return view("bca.bca", [
        "result" => $result
        ]);
```

my view

```
@if ($result['AccountDetailDataSuccess'])
{{ $result['AccountNumber'] }}
{{ $result['Currency'] }}
{{ $result['Balance'] }}
{{ $result['AvailableBalance'] }}
{{ $result['FloatAmount'] }}
{{ $result['HoldAmount'] }}
{{ $result['Plafon'] }}
@elseif ($result['AccountDetailDataFailed'])
{{ $result['English'] }}
{{ $result['Indonesian'] }}
{{ $result['AccountNumber'] }}
@endif
```

and this the result if I `var_dump($result)`

```
array(2) { ["AccountDetailDataSuccess"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["AccountNumber"]=> string(10) "0201245680" ["Currency"]=> string(3) "IDR" ["Balance"]=> string(12) "118849999.53" ["AvailableBalance"]=> string(12) "118849999.53" ["FloatAmount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["HoldAmount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["Plafon"]=> string(4) "0.00" } } ["AccountDetailDataFailed"]=> array(0) { } }
```

How can I call just one single array from the JSON result ?

Comment: Can know how did you get the X-BCA-Signatue ?

Comment: @vishwasjadav if I'm not mistaken X-BCA-Signature is a combination. can get it in the BCA documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AccountNumber is located in the AccountDetailDataSuccess array, thus call

```
$result['AccountDetailDataSuccess'][0]['AccountNumber']
```

same for currency etc.

Comment: I prefer `echo '<pre>'; print_r($a); echo '</pre>';` sometimes over var_dump, because the layout is just a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks again bro, I'll your suggest